# How to deal with generic typed component used in template in Angular Dart? (MaterialChip)

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have problem using itemRendere and material chips. What I do have is

```
<material-chips >
                <material-chip *ngFor="let chip of data"
                               [value]="chip"
                               [removable]="true"
                               [selectionModel]="dataSelectionModel"
                               [itemRenderer]="dataOptionRenderer"
                >
                </material-chip>
            </material-chips>
```

Where

```
final SelectionModel<MyType> datasetSelectModel = SelectionModel<MyType>.multi();
List<MyType> get data=>dataSelectionModel.selectedValues.toList();
ItemRenderer<MyType> dataOptionRenderer= ...
```

So as for typesafety everything is fine - generic type of selection model and renderer is exactly the same. However this ends up with an error

```
Expected a value of type '(dynamic) => String', but got one of type '(MyType) => String'
```

Please note, that using selectionModel and renderer directly on material-chips tag yealds the same result - forcing me to have untyped item renderer (as this wroks in both cases)

How to deal with that such case in angular dart?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `directiveTypes` on your component

```dart
@Component(
  directiveTypes: [
    Typed<MaterialChipsComponent<MyType>>()
  ],
)
```